# Subform blocking Recordset.AddNew (Error 3027)

Tags: vba, ms-access

Having a subform displaying the same table used in recordset makes the table read only (error 3027). Getting rid of the subform fixes the problem. Similar setup works in my other form interface.

I tried to delete the subform, which fix the accessibility problem. But that would defeat the original UX purpose.

```
Option Explicit
Public UnitRS As DAO.Recordset
Public ModelRS As DAO.Recordset
Public NameUnitRecords As String
Public NameModelRecords As String

Public Sub Form_Load()
    'Initialization
    NameUnitRecords = "tblBatteriesMainRecordsUnits"
    NameModelRecords = "tblBatteriesRecordsModels"
End Sub

Private Sub SetUnitRecordsets()
    'Set the path to the Battery Records table
    Set UnitRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(NameUnitRecords, dbOpenDynaset)
End Sub

Private Sub txtBatteryID_AfterUpdate()
    'Set the recordset path for unit records
    Call SetUnitRecordsets

    'do a findfirst search for the Battery ID, using value from textbox txtBatteryID
    UnitRS.FindFirst "[Battery ID]=" & txtBatteryID

    'If no matching record, leave the other fields empty
    If UnitRS.NoMatch Then
    'If there is a matching record, then, grab the model number
    Else
        'as there is an existing record with model number, run a search on the model number and grab the model info
    End If
    'close recordset
    UnitRS.Close
    'check if the button can be enabled
End Sub

Private Sub cmbModelNumber_AfterUpdate()
    'Set the recordset path for model records    
    'do a findfirst search for the Model Number, using value from combobox cmbModelNumber
    'If no matching record, leave the other fields empty
    If ModelRS.NoMatch Then
     'If there is a matching record, then, grab the Model Info
    Else
    End If
    'close recordset 
    'check if the button can be enabled
End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveAndCLear_Click()
    Dim Response, strOldModelNumber

    'Set the recordset path for unit records
    Call SetUnitRecordsets
    'Set the recordset path for model records
    'close all related tables, queries and forms
    DoCmd.Close acTable, NameUnitRecords, acSaveYes
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmSubBatteriesMainRecordsUnits", acSaveYes

    'If a new model record is required
    ModelRS.FindFirst "[Model Number]='" & cmbModelNumber & "'"
    If ModelRS.NoMatch Then
        'msg box confirm model information
        'If user chooses yes
        If Response = vbYes Then
            'create new model record
            'this block could be done with "With...End" format for less error vulerability?
            'nah, unless it is repetitively called, it's too much work to inplement just the .addnew part
            'requery the two combobox to reflect newest changes
        'User chooses no
        Else
            'popup a message telling the user the battery and model record is not logged, but don't clear the field.
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    'need to find the record first, otherwise it will edit the first one
    UnitRS.FindFirst "[Battery ID]=" & txtBatteryID
    'store the old model number value
    strOldModelNumber = UnitRS("Model Number")
    'New record
    If UnitRS.NoMatch Then
        'create a new battery record
        UnitRS.AddNew
        UnitRS("Battery ID") = Me.txtBatteryID
    'If this is an edit on existing record
    Else
        'if the new value is the same as the old one
        If strOldModelNumber = cmbModelNumber Then
            'msgbox the same value, no change is done to the database
            MsgBox "the data is the same as the old record, no change is made to the record", vbInformation, "Same data"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'msg box confirm edit
            Response = MsgBox("Please confirm edit on existing record: " & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "BatteryID: " & txtBatteryID & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Model Number: " & cmbModelNumber, vbYesNo, "New Model Record Dectected")
            'If user chooses yes
            If Response = vbYes Then
                'goto edit mode
                UnitRS.Edit
            'if user chooses no
            Else
                'msgbox notify the user nothing is changed in the database
                MsgBox "Battery and Model record not logged, you may retry logging", vbInformation, "Record not logged"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
    'both changes the model number and comment field anyway
    UnitRS("Model Number") = Me.cmbModelNumber
    UnitRS("Comment") = Me.txtComment
    'commit update
    UnitRS.Update
    UnitRS.Close

    'clear all flieds
    'reset all locks    
    'requery the sub form to reflect the newest changes
    Me.subFrmBatteryRecords.Requery
End Sub
```

What I would like to achieve is to have a display in the form interface to show the content of the actual record table, so that the user knows what is in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with my code. There is a property option in the form object, it's called "record lock", somehow mine had "All Records" selected. By making it "No locks", the accessibility problem is gone.

[image: Form Property Sheet]